# JQuery - why I get error on ajax

Tags: jquery

I have simple question (how I was thinked), but I cant resolve it

code

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://google.com',
    crossDomain: true,
    type: 'HEAD',
    success: function() {
        alert("ok");
    },
    error: function() {
        alert("error");
    }
});
```

I get error, but google worked :) Why?

Version of JQuery: `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>`

How I can check exsist URL or not?

Comment: Because it is a Same Origin Policy violation

Comment: Arun P Johny, I must query url via php script?

Comment: that is one option... sent a request to your PHP server... let PHP do the job of getting the remote resource and return it back to the client

Comment: Thanks! And I have others options? I'd like client side code, if it possible.

Comment: not many unless the other resource implements them... you have JSONP and CORS as solutions but the target resource need to support them

Comment: Thank you! But why I can get request from server, but cant from client?

Comment: because the same origin policy is implemented by the browser

Comment: But reason? Why server can, but client not? I dont undestend..